# Sort a NSMutabale Array containing Objects of A class

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, sorting

I have a mutable Arra of objects of a class "Place".

I want to sort it on the basis of an attribute of objects "Place Name"..

so i saw some links...but not able to write proper code...

I am using

```
-[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]
```

can i get some example of how to use this -[NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector:]

pls help me out

Thanks

Comment: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/SortUsingSelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Im the [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is call the `localizedCompare:` on `NSString`, I assume that the name property is a NSString.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the case insensitive compare then use,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
          initWithKey:@"Place Name"
          ascending:YES
          selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sorter];
[yourObjectArrayt sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```